USB ports disabled after boot and before GUI
My wired USB keyboard and mouse stopped working. I installed a Bluetooth adapter to an unused USB header on the motherboard to get the input devices to work. That didn't work either. The keyboard and mouse work fine in the BIOS setup GUI, so it is not the hardware.
I tried booting with the Ubuntu live USB, but it also didn't work. Somewhere in the boot process an error message was displayed that no mounted media contains a live image, despite the fact that the system had booted off that very media.
Next I tried booting with Fedora (latest ISO 2024/04 burned to the same USB stick) to try-Fedora all USB ports, keyboard and mouse worked just fine.
Additional details:
Motherboard: MSI 970A-g46
CPU: AMD FX-8120
dmesg output
journalctl --boot=1

We'll need some more details for the best chance of a useful answer. What is your hardware (motherboard/laptop)? Are you able to post any of the exact error messages that you can find (including within the output of sudo dmesg and tail /var/log/messages)?

added the requested output. there is no messages file in /var/log. I have instead included the journalctl --boot=1 output as I think it may point us to the root cause. Thank you so much for your guidance.
